# Hide block if content is empty not working

Tags: blocks, theming

I want to hide an entiere block is it has not result.

I went into my view, then I add "Contextual filter", "Empty", "Hide view".

But my view is always hidden if I do this, and I don't understand why... (I have content in this view, but it could be empty).

Do display my view, I'm using this : https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/templates%21system%21region.html.twig/8

See my config :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot plz ?

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/2443457

Comment: It looks like it, but how do I fixe that ?

Answer (score 2):

Up solution :

In views, go to "advanced". At the very bottom, see "hide block if view is empty". Change it to yes and it will work.

Comment: I have checked it and it is not working in my case.